# Interpreting GAM results - Generalized Additive Model

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, generalized-additive-model

I got the following significance after running GAM, does that mean that the pattern of my 2 groups of data in `comparison_types` are distinct?

```
library(gam)
# smooth for stage and an additive effect for comparison_type
b <- gam(ssim_exp ~ s(stage) + comparison_type, data = df)
summary(b)
```

```
Call: gam(formula = ssim_exp ~ s(stage) + comparison_type, data = df)
Deviance Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-62.530 -31.541   2.451  31.209  58.640 

(Dispersion Parameter for gaussian family taken to be 1094.722)

    Null Deviance: 200770.4 on 170 degrees of freedom
Residual Deviance: 181723.9 on 166 degrees of freedom
AIC: 1688.904 

Number of Local Scoring Iterations: NA 

Anova for Parametric Effects
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
s(stage)          1     22    22.3  0.0204    0.8867    
comparison_type   1  18170 18170.1 16.5979 7.144e-05 ***
Residuals       166 181724  1094.7                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Anova for Nonparametric Effects
                Npar Df  Npar F  Pr(F)
(Intercept)                           
s(stage)              2 0.72923 0.4838
comparison_type
```

This is how the graphs look like when I plot them

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
library(ggplot2)
gg.ns30 <- ggplot(df,aes(x=stage, y=ssim_exp,col=comparison_type))+geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method='gam',formula=y ~ splines::bs(x, 10)) + facet_grid(comparison_type ~.)
print(gg.ns30)
```

[image]

Specifically, can I say that the pattern of my data in `complete` group and `functions` group are distinct?

Comment: Your GAM only includes `comparison_type` as a parametric effect, which means you are only modelling different means but not different "patterns" (which is contrast to the ggplot2 plot which fits separate models to each group). You probably should investigate a model `ssim_exp ~ s(stage, by = comparison_type) + comparison_type`. Ensure that `comparison_type` is a factor (and not a character vector). Don't forget model diagnostics and plotting your model results.

Comment: Also, your dependent variable seems to be a percentage in which case the Gaussian family is not really appropriate.